# The background page isn't displaying

Tags: html, css

[image: Heres the code for the css]

I have put the path as you can see but when I load this code on my site it actually doesn't display the background for some unknown reason.

Here is what I see on the site :

[image: Here is the result]

Comment: Have you tried removing the background-color from `html body`?

Comment: Go to developer tools. On chrome ctrl+i check console for errors.

Comment: try adding a \ before your address

Comment: @RaminFarajpour that did solve my problem but why is it so sensitive as in why does it need the / before the address ?

Comment: it refers to root of the structure you choose for the project

Answer (score 0):

please try using the relative path like this: "../images/page-background.png"

regards,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `background-image-url` line is pointing to the following directory. `root/resources/styles/Webstar-Website/resources/images/page-background.png`

Instead you'll want to use this url. `./images/page-background.png`

In CSS all directories that you use are relative to the location of the file you are editing. If you were to move your CSS file, you would have to rewrite the directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: (images/page-background.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path to be sure, and clear you cache

background-image:url("http://www.site.ext/Webstar-Website/resources/images/page-background.png");

Answer (score 0):

It's look your URL is wrong, try this

```
background-image : url("http://yourwebsitedomain/resources/images/page-background.png") ;
```

Or you can using relative path instead to call the image

```
background-image : url("../images/page-background.png") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `\` before your address

it refers to root of the structure you choose for the project